# USB hub in monitor works on Mac but glitchy with my PC

Tags: windows-10, usb

I have a [Dell U3219Q](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-32-4k-usb-c-monitor-u3219q/apd/210-aqzz/monitors-monitor-accessories) monitor which has a USB hub and KVM integrated into it. When I connect it to my Windows 10 PC over either the USB-C or USB-A cable the USB connection is intermittent somehow. The mouse and keyboard randomly drop input for a second or two, and the DAC for my headphones errors and disconnects. The webcam seems to work fine.

When I connect the same USB-C cable to my Macbook Pro they all work perfectly. The peripherals also work perfectly in Windows when connected directly to the PC.

The PC is a desktop with a [Z390 Aorus Pro Wifi](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10) motherboard. I've tried connecting to several different USB ports as well as updating Windows and the motherboard firmware; no improvement.

Anybody know how I can debug the USB connection and figure out what's happening? What drivers might need updating to get the hub to work better, like it does on a mac?

Comment: Do I understand right that the flaky connection is PC-KVM-monitor, but is fine for PC-monitor? In that case, could you try another KVM?

Comment: The KVM is part of the monitor and I don’t have another.  Keyboard, mouse, webcam plug into the USB ports on the monitor. Monitor has two USB uplink cables, and I can choose which is paired with each video input. So my windows desktop is connected over DisplayPort and the USB-A uplink, and the MacBook uses a single USB-C (thunderbolt) connection to send video and receive all the input from the peripherals. So if I plug in the laptop the monitor automatically comes in and switches inputs. 

But monitor -> PC is flaky regardless of which usb uplink I use.

Comment: 1)How often does the issue happen with the PC? ex: every 5min, once a day, etc. 2)Does the issue happen if JUST the PC is plugged into the monitor & the second PC is disconnected? 3)Have you contacted Dell? I wonder if there is a FW update for the monitor, the [support page doesn't seem to work for that monitor](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?IsTag=False&Selection=dell-u3219q-monitor&IsInvalidSelection=True) else I'd check

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a link to the manual](http://ftp.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_Display/dell-u3219q-monitor_User%27s-Guide_en-us.pdf), pg58 shows the KVM function. Which appears to simply be a USB hub with two up-links: USB-C & USB-B (goes to USB-A) so I guess when you switch the monitor input it switches the hub uplink.

1. Since it appears to be a glorified hub I wouldn't think you'd need a hub driver, I can't find a driver for it on dells site.
2. Only other thought is if you updated Z390 mobo UEFI/BIOS (latest=F12k) then I'd also update its USB drivers, but I couldn't find those. Might want to update the 'Intel Serial I/O driver'. I also saw a 'USB Blocker' under Utilities, not sure what that is about, but you likely don't want that

How often does the disconnect/flakeyness happen? Could you see if it happens in the BIOS? Or a linux live CD/USB session? This is a technique HW vendors confirm if Windows or its drivers are causing the issue vs a HW problem

### --EDIT

I found some things that might be useful with [my google-fu (*`U3219Q update site:dell.com`*)](https://www.google.com/search?q=U3219Q%20update%20site%3Adell.com):

3. [More manuals](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-u3219q-monitor/docs), one of the manuals (pg6) mentions a 'Dell Display Manage' program that lets you control the input within a PC (vs monitor OSD menu) that indicates a HOTKEY combo that can trigger it. So maybe you are hitting that hotkey triggering the KVM & when the second macbook isn't connecting it just switches back to the PC. I'm not sure IF a default hotkey is setup or that the below picture is the default.
   [image]
4. Driver tab isn't working, but google found two monitor FW updates:

   - https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=956p7
   - https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=d269v
5. [Troubleshooting guide specific to this monitor model](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000125522/dell-u3219q-monitor-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide) shows how to factory reset it which I'd try.

Comment: RE timing: It really varies which has given me false hope that it was fixed several times. Typically it's pretty bad, maybe an 800 ms input pause every 5-25 seconds. I'm timing it now and it's been fairly consistently better over USB-C (so plugged into GPU) than I had noticed before.

Comment: 800ms pause only, that might be hard to troubleshoot, I thought you were talking multiple seconds at least. I can appreciate though any delay happening often could get annoying. You haven't noticed it with any particular key combination as I noted in #3? Did you try #4 FW update? #5 factory reset monitor?

Comment: #3 no, it's not a key stroke, I test it by just moving the mouse in little circles and waiting for the hitch. Or typing an ordinary sentence and at some point a keyup event will get dropped and it will act like I'm holding down one of the letters. I updated the Monitor firmware and Intel Serial I/O driver, rebooted everything, but still no change.

Then yesterday I tried a bunch of different USB ports and found one that seemed to work well! ...but then I went back to a port that was misbehaving and now that one is working too... so it feels like a temporary lull but I can't repro right now.

Comment: Well, it's still working! It was messed up, I switched USB ports twice and it remained messed up, tried another and it worked. And a couple days later it's still working on all the ports. I feel like I'm missing something key here, but this is the first time I've had it working in a long time, after following your suggestions. So thanks for all your help @gregg; I will and give you the bounty, even though I'm not sure which step precisely might help the next person with this exact problem.

Comment: Well, after a reboot but no other changes I can think of the hitches are back. Interesting that it's intermittent somehow. Guess I'll try the swap-to-lots-of-ports trick to see if that triggers anything again.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. 1)Does the issue happen if JUST the PC is plugged into the monitor & the second PC is disconnected 2)Do you have another Win10 PC to try it on? If not can you see if the problem can be seen in BIOS or Linux live CD/USB? 3)Have you done that monitor factory reset? Although problem APPEARS to be the PC since its the common denominator 4)Have you contacted Dell?

Answer (score 0):

The
[Dell UltraSharp U3219Q Monitor User’s Guide](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-hr/product-support/product/dell-u3219q-monitor/docs)
describes a setting that might relate to the delay problem, called Response Time:

[image]

It's probably currently set to Normal, at 8 ms.
Try to toggle it to Fast, 5 ms.

If that doesn't improve the problem, there are Windows drivers and firmware
that you could download from
[Support for Dell U3219Q | Drivers & Downloads](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-hr/product-support/product/dell-u3219q-monitor/drivers).

If nothing helps, I would suggest contacting Dell Support as last chance.

Comment: I suspect thats related to the video/display/LCD timing, but never hurts to try especially considering there is a KVM/superhub in it

Comment: Yeah, no change here except for introducing some odd ghosting artifacts. Switched it back to Normal :)  But worth a short